# GWT, Eclipse, UIBinder template and DataGrid

Tags: eclipse, gwt, datagrid, uibinder

I have Eclipse with GWT Designer installed. When I open an UIBinder template in Design View, and place a DataGrid onto a panel, I cannot configure columns, because there are no column widgets (like TextColumn) on a widget palette in the "Cell Widgets" category. When I use Java template instead of UIBinder template for my view, everything is fine, and I can configure DataGrid widget by adding columns of different types as they appear on the widget palette.
Is it something wrong with my Eclipse installation, or it is an expected behavior?

Widgets Palette when editing UIBinder XML template file:

### [image: Widgets Palette when editing UIBinder XML template file]

Widgets Palette when editing Java template file
[image: Widgets Palette when editing Java template file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is the right way you can only define the widget `Data Grid` in the ui-binder but you have to populate columns and its data using the java counterpart. Data grid is meant to be a grid that displays data that is retrieved dynamically and so the columns have to be added according to the needs. If you can have a look at the gwt-showcase [here](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDataGrid) example of data grid you might get an idea of using it using `Data Provider`.

Comment: So I can configure columns with java-based templates, and cannot with uibinder-based templates?

Comment: @Uniqus yes exactly...we have to go through the pain to handle 2 templates but yes that's the only way !